# Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

I'm going through the [NRAO Essential Radio Astronomy course](https://science.nrao.edu/opportunities/courses/era) and on the section about Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation, it mentions that BB radiation is $T_0 = 2.725 \pm 0.002$ K equating to "frequency of peak brightness" ~ 160 GHz.

Could someone spell out the factors that give this result please?
I have seen this figure quoted in another answer to a CMB question, but cannot find the factors.

Comment: Heh heh. Click bait title?

Comment: What do you mean by "factors that give this result"? Which result? The temperature is determined by observation. Are you asking how 2.7K corresponds to 160 GHz?

Comment: Your search might be more fruitful if you ask why a "blackbody spectrum" corresponding to $2.7\,\mathrm{K}$ has a peak frequency near $160\,\mathrm{GHz}$.

Comment: This is a measured property of the CMB that was measured by the [FIRAS instrument on COBE](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/CMB.html).

Answer (score 5):

The spectral radiance of a blackbody,
$$
B_\nu\left(\nu,\,T\right)=\frac{2 h \nu^3}{c^2}\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{h\nu}{k_BT}\right)-1},
$$
peaks around $\nu=$160GHz when $T=$2.725K. See the Wikipedia article [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck's_law).